# Anyone know if IG or Plus500 are scams or not?

Tags: stocks, options, futures, online-trading, cfd

I have been doing some research into online trading and came across 2 platforms that are pretty good and user friendly.
http://www.IG.com and http://www.plus500.com
I have read quite a lot of reviews and many people claim that these sites are scams and once you put your money in, you might as well kiss it goodbye.
Also people complain about positions not being closed for profit taking etc.
Has anyone actually used any of these sites or know if they are in fact scams or legitimate sites?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

> people claim that these sites are scams

I would like to know which idiots or which website says so. And I would say you haven't done your research properly.

At the bottom of the page you can see this, on IG's website, **very important quote**

> authorised and regulated by the Financial Conduct Authority
>
> Plus500UK Ltd is authorised and regulated by the Financial Conduct Authority

Secondly you go and check the authencity of the firm in question [on this link](https://register.fca.org.uk/).

> your money in, you might as well kiss it goodbye

This might be true because they trade in products, which if you don't understand you will more or less will loose your money.

N.B. I have an account with IG for the past 5 years and they haven't scammed me yet.

Answer (score 0):

Like all other trading brokers in the industry, they both have been acknowledged with mixed reviews. Before signing up, it’s important to know whether they are running a legitimate operation or not.  You can see BinaryOptionsTrading-Review.com, judgebinaryoptions.com etc.  to inquiries about these sites. They conduct in-depth research to identify the legitimacy of each brokers present in the market. Hope it will help you in making the right decision.